# select audio output divece when using QSoundEffect

Tags: c++, qt, audio, output, avaudioplayer

I am using `QSoundEffect` to play loops of some short `.wav` files. This class was the solution for me because it allow us to play low latency sounds.

Everything was fine but now I need to select the output device but I haven’t found the way to do this with `QSoundEffect`. I know that using `QAudioDeviceInfo` I can get a list of the available devices and use one of them  in the constructor of a `QAudioOutput` object to play a wav file   but `QAudioOutput` doesn't allow us to make low latency loops.

So the thing is that I need the functionality of selecting the audio output device that `QAudioOutput` and `QAudioDeviceInfo` but the ability of playing play low latency loops that `QSoundEffect` offers.

In other words I have all the pieces of my desired solution but I don’t know how to put them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qt5.7 the alsa qt plugin (libqtaudio_alsa.so) is using the device "default", this you can configure in /etc/asound.cfg or ~/.asoundrc
In the example below I'm selecting dmix plugin as default device:

```
pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_key_add_uid 0
    slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
}
pcm.dsnooped {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1025
    slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
}

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixed"
    capture.pcm "dsnooped"
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue time ago  with QT 5.1.1 like this :

```
 QByteArray audio_data;
          inputFile.seek(44); // skip wav header
          audio_data = inputFile.readAll();
          for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
              audio_data.append(audio_data);
          }
          QBuffer* audio_buffer = new QBuffer(&audio_data);
          audio_buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
          audioOutput->start(audio_buffer);//start test playback
          connect(audioOutput,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),this,SLOT(finishedPlaying(QAudio::State)));
          while(audioOutput->state() == QAudio::ActiveState){
              qeloop.exec();
          }
          audio_data.clear();
```

Comment: What is `qeloop` in this snippet?